# Do I need to have the Gods & Kings expansion to play Brave New World?

Tags: civilization-5, civilization-5-gods-and-kings, civilization-5-brave-new-world

I want to skip the Gods and Kings expansion. Does anyone know if this is possible? That is, will the expansion Brave New World work without Gods and Kings?

Comment: Brave New World won't be out for at least a few weeks.

Comment: @fbueckert Hm. Usually I'd agree with you, but compatibility info is an edge-case that is often available beforehand. No answer to this question necessitates knowledge of Brave New World mechanics, which is why we'd usually close the question as unanswerable.

Comment: @RavenDreamer Well said. This is a *very* useful question to know *now*, as pre-orders for Brave New World are available already.

Comment: I'm not sure if that information has been provided, but fair enough.

Answer (score 17):

Civilization V is a Steamworks title (i.e., all versions require Steam). As such, I consulted the [store page of Brave New World](http://store.steampowered.com/app/235580/)

[image]

The game is listed as DLC, and steam indicates that it *only* requires the base game to play.

In short, you are totally okay to pass up Gods and Kings, since Brave New World contains all the changes (espionage, religion, combat, etc.)

This would mean, then, that if you will get all of the benefits from Gods and Kings *except* for the civs, relegating the expansion to a simple bundle of Civs and leaders, to those who already own Brave New World.

Comment: You answered after me, but you have a free hand arrow...+1

Comment: The faith screenshot is probably from a combination of G&K and Brave New World (You can expect the devs to work with G&K included), I read somewhere that some improvements from G&K are included specifically for those people who don't have/want G&K(don't remember where though). The expansion is balanced with G&K in mind though...

Comment: @Arperum Nope! Brave New World has all of the Gods and Kings stuff by default (minus the Civs)

Comment: @RavenDreamer Does BNW really contains the religions and spy part? Because that would reduce G&K to just adding a couple Civs.

Comment: @Arperum That it does, and... that it does.

Answer (score 9):

According to the Steam page, it only requires the base game of Sid Mieier's Civilization 5.

[image]

This is consistent with what Amazon has listed:
[image]

This would be consistent with past Civilization titles and their expansions. [Here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/17313/are-warlords-and-beyond-the-sword-two-separate-expansions-for-civilization-iv-or) is a question for reference covering Civilization 4 Warlords and Beyond the Sword.

Answer (score 3):

I can tell you for certain that the game is playable without Gods and Kings. All the mechanics from G&K are included, but the civilizations are not.

Comment: The question is about the Brave New World expansion that's coming out soon. Of course the game works without G&K, but will BNW work without G&K?

Comment: @PaulMarshall That's pretty much what he says, he's just a little ambiguous